# mouse cannot click-and-hold

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, GNOME Version 42.5, OS Type 64bit, Windowing System "Wayland".

I suffer the problem, potentially a bug, that the mouse cannot grab a thing. Examples are:

- When I try to grab a scroll-bar and move it down, so the website scrolls down, then neither the scrollbar nor the website will move down as I move the mouse. Gladly, once I release the mousebutton, the scrollbar jumps to the present location of my mouse and the website will jump down.
- When I try to mark text (e.g., for copying) by moving the mouse to the beginning of that text, then click-and-hold the left mouse-button, then move the mouse to the end of the text passage, then releasing the mouse, only then I will see the portion of marked text. Instead, I would expect to see a highlighting that moves in real-time as my mouse is moving with the held button.
- When I try to grab google maps (or any map or image for that matter), again by click-and-hold the left mouse button and then moving the mouse where I wish the object to move to, *nothing will happen*. That is extremely frustrating because it actually means I cannot plan any travel routes on my PC.

1. Is the problem known?
2. How can I report it? (I tried Alt+F2+ "buntu-bug " but there is no suitable category and when I choose "other category" then I receive a rejection notice).
3. Can the problem be fixed?

The problem is independent of the mouse. I tested the laptop's touchpad as well as three other external USB-based computer mice. On the same laptop, I do not suffer from the problem under windows.

Comment: have you tried logging out and back in again using X11? Does the same occur? [edit] the answer in to your question.

Comment: Did you try a different mouse?

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @24601 worked: I used

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

However, today the problem reoccured, and a repeat of the attempt does no longer fix the issue.